# What do you think is causing this crash with a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, swiftui

I am building my first SwiftUI application. I am using XCode 11.4.1 with Swift 5.1 and targeting iOS 13.2.

The code was working fine until I added an .onDelete() to a ForEach. the onDelete() needs to delete a row from a Core Data object store. The method function executes and succeeds, the data is in fact deleted from the object store correctly. Watching it in the debugger i can see it makes it to the end of the method that is doing the deletion and then crashes AFTER the method is done, but before it returns back to my code. The only error message I see is the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) which is on the AppDelegate right at the top of the definition of the class.

Here is a code fragment where this occurs;

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
                var managedObjectContext

  @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: LocationHeader.getAllLocationHeaders())
                var locationHeaders: FetchedResults<LocationHeader>

  @State private var newLocationHeader = ""

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        Section(header: Text("Add Location")) {
          HStack {
            TextField("New Location", text: self.$newLocationHeader)
            Button(action: { 
              let newLocationHeader = LocationHeader(context: self.managedObjectContext)
              newLocationHeader.name = "This is a test name 3"
              newLocationHeader.date = Date()
              newLocationHeader.id = UUID()
              newLocationHeader.details = LocationDetail(context: self.managedObjectContext)
              newLocationHeader.details?.id = UUID()
              newLocationHeader.details?.lattitude = 22.22
              newLocationHeader.details?.longitude = 33.33
              newLocationHeader.details?.detailNarrative = "this is the detail"
              do {
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
              } catch {
                print(error)
              }
              self.newLocationHeader = "data was updated"
            }){
              Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .imageScale(.large)
            }
          }
        }.font(.headline)
        Section(header: Text("Locations")) {
          ForEach(self.locationHeaders) { locationHeader in
            LocationView(name: locationHeader.name, date: locationHeader.date)
          }
          .onDelete(perform: deleteSelectedRow)
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Here"), displayMode: .inline)
      .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }
  }

  func deleteSelectedRow(at offSets: IndexSet) -> Void {

    if (offSets.first != nil) {
      let deleteItem = self.locationHeaders[offSets.first!]
      self.managedObjectContext.delete(deleteItem)
      do {
        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
      }
      catch {
        print(error)
      }
    }

    return

  }
```

Does anyone have any idea how to proceed? I have looked at the code for a while now but I do not see anything wrong. I thought maybe it was a forced unwrapping of the offSets.first so I wrapped that in a conditional check for nil, but I do not see how that would ever by nil anyway on a .onDelete from a ForEach (but still safer to have the nil check there, so I left it in place).

Any thoughts and ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have tried a number of things, but I found that if I comment out the self.managedObjectContext.save() call, it does not crash. Of course the view updates with the deletion of the row, but the underlying data store does not get updated without the call to save(), so that is not workable, but does show that the problem is in the save(). I still do not know what the problem is, just that it is in the save().

Comment: were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: A reason could be that an instance of `LocationView ` is still used in another view when the object is being deleted. Apparently SwiftUI caches views even outside the hierarchy and any updates to observed properties seem to still call `body`. Force unwrapping a property (like `name` or `date`) could then cause a crash. Can you post the implementation of `LocationView`?

Comment: I did not really solve the problem, but I did make it go away. The context contained two entities with a reference between them. I ended up merging them into one entity and hence with no reference, and it stopped crashing. I suspect I had something in my code wrong in terms of how it was following the reference but because I just got rid of the reference I never did figure out what the problem was. Not a great solution, but it worked at the time. Thanks for the tips. Always more to learn!